# Left an uncooked thawed store made pizza in the car for 4 hours in 54 degree weather

Tags: pizza

Left an unfrozen uncooked store made pizza in the car for 4 hours in 54 degree weather. Is this safe to cook?

Comment: 54 degree fahrenheit or celsius?

Comment: Definitely: COOK IT NOW while waiting for an answer, and don't consume until you have one.

Comment: Many food safety standard suggest that "2-4 hours at 5 to 60 centigrade means consume immediately, do not refrigerate or freeze". If "cooking it" is equal to "immediately consume", I am unable to responsibly answer, but likely someone here can.

Comment: It's fine. The most perishable item in a frozen pizza is the dough: everything else is so saturated in preservatives, it would probably be fine at a much *higher* temp. The operative term in this case is "water activity": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_activity#Food_safety. The available water in frozen pizza is distributed in such a manner as to make bacterial growth sluggish.